# WorkflowView force refresh when new child Activity is added

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

My application is using workflow designer rehosting to let end-users develop workflows. I have an Activity available that requires the user set some state. To accomplish this, in the designer I override Initialize(Activity) and show a form which I then use to set values in my Activity. This is for setting the state when the Activity is initially added. I also have a double click event handler in the designer in case they need to edit that state later.

I now have a situation where, depending on the values in the form, I may need to add or remove a child activity. I've been successful in adding the activity, but not always in getting it to show up in the designer.

When Initialize is called, there are no child activities. I may need to add a child Activity. At this point, it works fine and shows up in the designer. The problem happens when they edit it later by double clicking. In my designer, I override OnActivityChanged to detect this. I make the same call to add a child, however the designer is not getting updated. Oddly enough, when the situation is such that the child is removed, the view updates fine.

Stepping through with the debugger shows that I am adding a child activity to the Activities collection. Normally when I have problems updating the view, I can make a call to IComponentChangeService.OnComponentChanged, but I can't seem to find a way to make this work.

Any suggestions?

It looks like I needed to use RemoveActivities and InsertActivities in the designer. It seems as if the designer doesn't listen to list change events on the Activities list. Does anyone know if this is how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my situation, I determined I needed to use RemoveActivities and InsertActivities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your OnActivityChanged event handler?

```
TypeDescriptor.Refresh(e.Activity);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris. I've already gotten it to work by using RemoveActivities and InsertActivities, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind if I run into a similar problem.